# wildfly cli connect fails, running as windows service

Tags: wildfly

Wildfly application server is installed and started on windows. I am trying to use the CLI to do a connect which throws the below error. **I am able to connect via URL.** The jboss-cli.xml is pointing to the `8083 port` which I am using. Windows Defender Firewall is off. My question is - Can I connect using CLI when the server is running as a service (It's not launched as standalone). if yes,  can someone help me with the error, please?

```
C:\wildfly\bin> jboss-cli.bat --connect --controller=remote+http://localhost:8083
```

Failed to connect to the controller:

> The controller is not available at localhost:8082:
> java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to
> remote+http://localhost:8082. The connection failed: WFLYPRT0053:
> Could not connect to remote+http://localhost:8082. The connection
> failed: Connection refused: no further information Press any key to
> continue . . .

I also tried the flags --user and --password.

Comment: Is 8083 the HTTP port or management port? Also the error message says it's trying to connect to 8082. The default management port is 9990.

Comment: How do I set the management port? I have modified  jboss-cli.xml to point to 8083 as default which I am trying from the CLI

Comment: You'd need to update WildFly itself first. Can you connect to port 9990?

Comment: no cant connect to 9990 either. As mentioned, the server is running as windows service

Comment: Running as a Windows service shouldn't really matter. The HTTP management port is defined in the configuration you boot with. Likely the `standalone.xml`.